Uninstall all packages from specific group
In my pyproject.toml I have configured a "normal" and a "dev" configuration, like so:
[tool.poetry]
name = "project_name"
version = "0.2.0"
description = "Project description"
authors = ["me"]
license = "no one is allowed to use this code except myself ;)"
readme = "README.md"
package-mode = false

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
exceptiongroup = ">=1.2,<2.0"
tabulate = ">=0.9,<1.0"
trio = ">=0.25,<1.0"
rich = ">=13.7,<14.0"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^8.2.1"
asynctest = "^0.13.0"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.23.7"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

In my build script (which is actually a Docker script in my case, but it could be any other build script) I want to first install all dependencies of both groups:
poetry install --with dev

then run the unit tests of my project and afterwards uninstall the dev dependencies again:
# ! PSEUDOCODE !
poetry remove * --group dev

However, I'm facing the problem that poetry seems to disallow uninstalling all dependencies of a group at once. There is the poetry remove command, but it needs a package to be specified.
Is there some option I am overlooking which lets me obtain a wildcard-like effect?
For completeness, here is my Dockerfile (Disclaimer: This file is "work in progress"):
ARG PY_VERSION=3.10-slim
FROM python:${PY_VERSION} AS pyimg
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV APP_PORT="8080"

COPY src/*.py ./
COPY pyproject.toml ./
COPY poetry.lock ./

COPY README.md ./

RUN apt update -y
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry install --with dev   # Install dev dependencies so that unittests can be run inside the container

# Run unittests, here
# RUN poetry remove --group dev
# RUN pip uninstall poetry -y

EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}

RUN touch config.ini
# CMD python${PY_VERSION} app.py


poetry install  --sync will remove unnecessary dependencies, including from a group.  But typically you'd want to build your dev image on top of your production one, not the other way around.

You mean I should add a second dockerfile referencing the prod image using FROM and install the dev dependencies in that one?

This is beyond the scope of this question but you can use multi stage build https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/

It's not exactly an answer to the question. However, normally you can solve a problem in multiple ways and this is a perfect valid solution to keep the production image clean of testing code. My original idea to solve this problem was to use poetry dependency groups, but I'm perfectly fine with the docker approach. My use-case is even mentioned in the link you gave in the section https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage.
